# Target .Netcore 2.1 on Mac

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

How do I target .Net Core 2.1 on a Mac?
When I change the .csproj content to target netstandard2.1 I get the following error

> "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(150,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDKdoes not support targeting .NET Standard
>   2.1.  Either target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.1.
>   [/Users/user/Documents/Projects/vsCode/DotNet/AlexaDemo/data/data.csproj]"

Dotnet --info returns

> dotnet --info .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:
>   2.1.300  Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Mac OS X  OS Version:  10.13  OS
>   Platform: Darwin  RID:         osx.10.13-x64  Base Path:
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 2.1.0   Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
>     2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
>     2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0
>   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0
>   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0
>   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5
>   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
>   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

I am using vsCode on Mac if that makes any difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there is no dotnetstandard2.1 as of yet.
classlib projects should target NET Standard 2.0 and console, mvc and api projects should target netcoreapp2.1.

Answer (score -1):

I believe targeting a specific release of dotnet Core is not available on VS or VSCode for mac. However, using Rider #jetbrains, I was able to choose the framework version when creating a new solution.

Best

Comment: Welcome! This is a very low quality answer.